# Open elec can't connect

Tags: kodi, openelec

Hello I can't update openELEC on my Raspberry because I can't connect to internet.

My configuration is the default DHCP `192.168.1.16`. I active the ssh and from an other PC I try to ping something, it work.

```
##############################################
#                  OpenELEC                  #
#             http://openelec.tv             #
##############################################

OpenELEC (official) Version: 6.0.1
OpenELEC:~ # ping www.google.fr
PING www.google.fr (172.217.16.67): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=0 ttl=56 time=32.854 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=1 ttl=56 time=33.525 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=2 ttl=56 time=33.456 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=3 ttl=56 time=33.169 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=4 ttl=56 time=33.146 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=5 ttl=56 time=33.298 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=6 ttl=56 time=33.227 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=7 ttl=56 time=33.125 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=8 ttl=56 time=33.890 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=9 ttl=56 time=33.803 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.67: seq=10 ttl=56 time=32.610 ms
^C
--- www.google.fr ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 11 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 32.610/33.282/33.890 ms
OpenELEC:~ #
```

Why I can't get addons or skin on openELEC?

Comment: start at least with an error message that openelec might show you, or with relevant logs.

Comment: If you can ping google from the command line then you're connected to the internet. That suggests that something is wrong with OpenElec, not your network connection. There are some suggestions under [this](https://github.com/OpenELEC/OpenELEC.tv/issues/4333) bug report that might help.

Answer (score 1):

The serever of open-elec were offline, now it work.